Livewire V3 wire:model on null despite initializing object class
I'm using Livewire V3 to create an edit & create form in one. I've seen the idea of passing the model into the mount method and if no model is passed it'll create an object which it's doing. But when assigning wire:model="domain.name" and trying to submit the form, it says name is null. It is because it's the create form, why isn't livewire linking it up and setting it?
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Site\Forms\Domains;

use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Domain;

class DomainForm extends Component
{
    public Domain $domain;

    public function mount(Domain $domain)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'domain.name' => ['required']
        ];
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.site.forms.domains.domain-form');
    }
}

<x-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="domain.name" placeholder="e.g: example.com" />


In Livewire 3, binding directly to Eloquent models has been disabled
Version 3 maintains support for this behaviour via a configuration item in config/livewire.php
'legacy_model_binding' => true,

By setting legacy_model_binding to true, Livewire will handle Eloquent model properties exactly as it did in version 2.
